# A STL object instantiated in a function is taking memory on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, dynamic-memory-allocation, lifetime

I'm adding objects to a vector in a function. The code looks like the following:

```
class MyObj
{
   int a;
   int b;

   MyObj( int ai, int bi )
   {
      this->a = ai;
      this->b = bi;
   }
};

vector<MyObj> myVec;

void foo()
{
    MyObj objInst( 10, 20 );
    myVec.push_back( objInst );
}
```

I expect the objects are taking space from the stack and hence after return of the function their memory should be released. To my experience that's not the case i.e the objects in the container can be accessed outside the function with no problem so far.
Can someone please enlighten me why that's the case?
Do STL containers copy the data of the object passed to them and keep it somewhere int the heap or in the global memory?

Thanks a lot @Louen for the comments. Read this article and learned a lot.  https://www.internalpointers.com/post/c-rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-beginners

Comment: "I expect the objects are taking space from the [stack] and hence after return of the function their memory should be released."  Yes.  When you create an object (such as std::string) in automatic memory, the object gets it's memory from the automatic memory.  The automatic memory is released upon exiting the scope.  And when std::string is released, it release any heap memory it is managing.   (You will find plenty of negative comments for using globals ... I simply do not.)

Comment: from wikipedia:  "The Standard Template Library (STL) is a software library for the C++ programming language that influenced many parts of the C++ Standard Library. It provides four components called algorithms, containers, functions, and iterators.[1]"    I think you are probably using the "C++ Standard Library" that came with your compiler, and not the STL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the breakdown of what happens.

Your vector `myVec` being defined outside of a function body is a **global** variable. 
This means it is created at the beginning of the program execution (before `main()` is called)  and destroyed at the end (when `main()` returns).

In your `foo()` functions you create an instance of your class `MyObj` on the stack, then you add a **copy** of it to your global vector.

You can check that it is copied by monitoring the copy constructor of `MyObj`, as shown [here](https://ideone.com/DkmNDB).

When `foo()` ends the instance of `MyObj` you created is destroyed, but the instance created from the copy lives on in the global vector. It is only destroyed when the global vector itself is destroyed, i.e. after the end of `main()`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. I assume that means, it's much more efficient to add pointers to containers than objects themselves? My only problem with that is the coding style gets a bit harder to follow. E.g with map, you can access elements using [] but with a pointer you have to repeated use reference e.g (*myMap)[key] instead of myMap[key]. Do you have any insight or comments on that?

Comment: Pointers come with their own set of problems, but one direction you can look at to avoid unnecessary copies of objects is **move semantics**

Answer (score 1):

> To my experience that's not the case i.e the objects in the container can be accessed outside the function with no problem so far.

You see a copy in the container, not the object that was in created in stack space in `foo`.

> Can someone please enlighten me why that's the case?

You have already found the explanation.

> Do STL containers copy the data of the object passed to them and keep it somewhere int the heap or in the global memory?

That is true for your use case with a `std::vector`. It's not true in general. `std::array` is an exception. It does not use heap memory.

Comment: Small caveat: `std::array`

Answer (score 1):

> Do STL containers copy the data of the object passed to them and keep it 
>   somewhere int the heap or in the global memory?

Yes.  (but note that most of the containers you use in std C++ are no longer part of the 'STL' ... more research for you.)

- Consider using `sizeof()` as a simple tool for you to investigate.

I use `std::string` in almost all my code, so consider this code snippet:

```
{
   std::string       a_s;    // empty string

   std::cout << "\n\n"
      << "\n  sizeof(empty std::string         type) " << std::setw(5) 
      << sizeof(std::string)
      << "\n  sizeof(empty std::string       object) " << std::setw(5) 
      << sizeof(a_s) << std::endl
      << "\n  a_s.size(                              " << std::setw(5) 
      << a_s.size()
      << "\n  contents                                   '" << a_s << "'" 
      << std::endl;

   // add 100 chars into a_s
   a_s += "50 chars>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>|"
      "\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<50 chars";

   std::cout
      << "\n  sizeof(100 char string         object) " << std::setw(5) 
      << sizeof(a_s)
      << "\n  a_s.size()                             " << std::setw(5) 
      << a_s.size()
      << "\n  contents                                 '" << a_s << "'"  
      << std::endl;
}
```

With output:

```
  sizeof(empty std::string         type)    32
  sizeof(empty std::string       object)    32

  a_s.size(                                  0
  contents                                   ''

  sizeof(100 char string         object)    32
  a_s.size()                               100
  contents                                 '50 chars>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>|
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<50 chars'
```

(Sorry, this format is too long for SO ... 100 chars shows fine on my console.)

An empty `std::string` uses 32 bytes, in this context 'in the automatic memory' (sometimes referred to as stack). After 100 chars are added to `a_s`, the 100 element `std::string` uses ... yes, only 32 bytes (also in automatic memory).

HOWEVER, `a_s.size()` reports there are 100 chars in that string.

So, 'where are the 100 chars stored?' is a good question, but not one you need to worry about. Use the object methods (for access and modification) and you shouldn't have problems.

NOTE that some `std::string` code attempts to pack small strings into the object, and thus uses no heap.  My LUbuntu uses `g++ v8.3.0`, I have not yet investigated if 'small' `std::strings` use 0 heap.  Because I am not sure what I would code differently because of that implementation detail.

Summary: Somewhere in your reading you missed the idea that standard containers such as `std::string`, are objects which are complex when compared to c-strings. The code of these standard container objects manages the use of heap, and the `std::string` contents are stored on heap (for most implementations). This 'heap management' is a common achievement for most of the standard containers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.